# query of ContentResolver returns null

Tags: java, android

I have two applications.

First application is to write data into ContentProvider, second application is to read. Data - just string

In first application I created ContentProvider class:

```
package myPackage;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.MatrixCursor;
import android.net.Uri;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class IBoxContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

    // Авторитет, используемый для доступа к провайдеру
    private static final String AUTHORITY = "myPackage.provider";
    // URI для доступа к данным
    private static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/data");
    // Коды для UriMatcher
    private static final int DATA = 1;
    // UriMatcher для сопоставления URI
    private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

    // Переменная для хранения строки
    private String data;

    static {
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "data", DATA);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        data = "";
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        if (uri.equals(CONTENT_URI)) {
            String[] columnNames = {"data"};
            MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(columnNames);
            cursor.addRow(new Object[]{data});
            return cursor;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {

        if (uri.equals(CONTENT_URI)) {
            String newData = values.getAsString("data");
            data = newData;
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(CONTENT_URI, null);
            return ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, 1);
        } else {

            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        if (uriMatcher.match(uri) == DATA) {
            String newData = values.getAsString("data");
            data = newData;
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(CONTENT_URI, null);
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        return "vnd.android.cursor.item/data";
    }
}
```

It is writing to Content using the following code:

```
values.put("data", myString);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://myPackage.provider/data");
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
Uri insertedUri = contentResolver.insert(uri, values);
```

In manifest of the first application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="myPackage">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ico_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <provider
            android:name="myPackage.IBoxContentProvider"
            android:authorities="myPackage.provider"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:process=":myPackage_content_provider_process">
        </provider>

        <activity.../>
            
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The second application try to take information into 1st App's Content Provider:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://myPackage.provider/data");
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
```

But Cursor is null...

It is worked correctly when I used:

```
android:sharedUserId="myPackage.sharedUserID"
```

But in my project I cannot use this way.

Can u help me to understand, why cursor is null? How can I get access to Con tentProvider from other application and read its data?

Comment: Think you have to add a `<queries>` tag in manifest file of second app.

Comment: Is query() returning null,? Then you should tell us.

Comment: @blackapps yes, query is returning null.

Comment: I added <queries> in manifest of 2d app, but it is not working.
<queries>
        <package android:name="myPackage"/>
</queries>

Comment: If query() is returning null then it is app a that returns null. You programmed it to return null. Or are you talking about the query() of app b?. I see it in the code. So tell why you return null. Add log statements in the query() code of the provider.  There are two query() members so tell about which one you are taking.

Comment: @blackapps
App A use only insert function, but App B use query.
I added log into IBoxContentProvider. While App A is inserting information into provider, log shows that provider works correctly (string var "data" comes to corrent string).

When i try to get information in App B by query function, query function returns null.

When i Used sharedUserId apps worked correctly: query returned cursor with string I need. But i have to not use sharedUserID for that case.

Comment: Sorry but you dont understand what i asked. If app b cals query() function on content resolver then contents privider query() function is called if everything goes ok. Now tell if the second one is called. If the second one returns null the first one will return null to. So tell what is going on. The furst one could return null without the second one being called.

Answer (score 0):

Content provider was found by 2d application when I added the following code to 2d app manifest:

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="myPackage"/>
    <provider android:authorities="myPackage.provider" />
</queries>
```

I just didn't know about provider tag in queries